# simple way to record video for a single pixel on the screen?

Tags: screenshot, pixel, screen-recording

I'd like to analyze streaming video of a process that's periodic but changes slowly over the course of hours. Is there a simple way in Mac OS X 10.7 to directly record what's happening at a single pixel over time?

(By "simple" I mean without doing a conventional screen record, splitting the video into frames, and taking pixel data from each frame.)

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by utilizing the `screencapture` command in OS X. Using the `-Rx,y,w,h` parameter, you can specify a section of the screen. Used in a bash script, you can save incremental screencapture images in a infinite loop.

For example, the following script will capture the pixel at `X:100`, `Y:200` and save it as `screenshot_#.png` once every second.

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=1
while true; do
    #Create output file name.
    output="screenshot_$counter.png"
    echo "Capturing: $output"
    #Screen capture a section of the screen x,y,w,h.
    screencapture -R100,200,1,1 "$output"
    #Increment counter.
    counter=$(($counter + 1))
    #Number of second to wait between taking screenshots.
    sleep 1
done
```

To stop it from running, just hit `Ctrl` + `C`.

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately, the `-R` argument is new in either OS X 10.8 or 10.9. It is not available in 10.7 and below.

Comment: My version of OS X (10.7) doesn't have the -R option for the screencapture command.